# Store static ggplot to variable as value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating multiple ggplots in a for loop, storing them in a list.
My problem is that the "data" parameter that I pass to the ggplot is changing on each iteration, and therefore when I later print the plots, they are all printed with the last revision of the "data" dataframe.

What I would like to do, is to save the ggplot statically into variable (by value) in a way that it will not reevaluate the "data" uppon printing.
any ideas?

For an example, if I will look into each an every ggplot in the list, it will use the last revision of 'scaleBounds' (from the last iteration) is the 'data' of the ggplot.

my code:

```
scalePlotList <- list()
for (i in 1:number_of_scales)
  {
    plot.new()
    row <- df[i,]

    min <- row$min
    max <- row$max
    you <- max(min(row$your_business,max),min)
    pinSeq <- seq(from=min,to=max,length.out=6)

    scaleBounds <-data.frame(x=c(pinSeq[1],pinSeq[2],pinSeq[2],pinSeq[1],pinSeq[2],pinSeq[3],pinSeq[3],pinSeq[2],pinSeq[3],pinSeq[4],pinSeq[4], pinSeq[3],pinSeq[4],pinSeq[5],pinSeq[5],pinSeq[4],pinSeq[5], pinSeq[6], pinSeq[6], pinSeq[5]),
                            y=c( 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,1,1 ),
                            t=c( 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5 ))

    currentPlot <- ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data=scaleBounds, mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,group=t,fill=-t)) + 
      scale_colour_brewer() +
      labs(x="",y="") +
      ylim(0,1.5) +
      geom_segment(aes(x=you,y=0,xend=you,yend=1.2), colour="#3d3d3d", size=3, lineend = "round") +
      geom_text(label="min", aes(x=pinSeq[1], y=0), size=5, colour="#fcfcfc", fontface="bold", hjust=-0.1, vjust=-.7) + 
      geom_text(label="max", aes(x=pinSeq[6], y=0), size=5, colour="#fafafa", fontface="bold", hjust=1.1, vjust=-.7) +
      geom_text(label="you", aes(x=you, y=.5), size=8, colour="#fafafa", fontface="bold", hjust=-0.1) +
      theme_nothing()

      scalePlotList[[length(scalePlotList)+1]] <- currentPlot

    }
```